# Why is the subhash key (H) of AES-GCM defined as such?

Tags: aes, aes-gcm

From what I've read in section 5.3 of [NIST 800-38D](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-38d/final) it states:

> The hash subkey, denoted H, is generated by applying the block cipher
>   to the “zero” block.

In [serious crypto](https://www.nostarch.com/seriouscrypto) J.P Aumasson describes the implementation of it as `H = AES(K,0)` for a single block of zeros, hence no block chaining mode, hence no IV as I understand it. Therefore the mapping between `H` and `K` should be universally constant.

The book notes:

> In GCM, GHASH doesn't use K directly in order to ensure that if GHASH's key is compromised, the master key K remains secret. Given K, you can get H by computing AES(K,0), but you can't recover K from that value since K acts as AES's key.

If the mapping is universally constant wouldn't it be the case that this could be pre-computed and available somewhere? (I wanted to say rainbow table here, but that probably doesn't quite apply based on what I read in [this response](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/24544/28601))

So is the strength just that storing this permutation space for later indexing is thought to be too large? Or is there more to it that what I laid out?

Comment: fixed plaintext variable K is not always a bijection, there can be multiple K where encrypting 0 gives the same H

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In GCM, GHASH doesn't use K directly in order to ensure that if GHASH's key is compromised, the master key K remains secret.

Actually, there's not why GCM was designed the way it was (it may be an effect, but not the reason).  Instead, the reasons were:

- To allow provable security (based on the assumption that the block cipher was a secure keyed random permutation).  If we used $k$ as both the block cipher key, and used as an input to compute the tag, we need to make additional assumptions on the block cipher.
- Because of the size mismatch; $h$ is 128 bits, $k$ is (at least, for AES) is either 128, 192 or 256 bits.  Yes, one could select an arbitrary section of $k$ as your $h$, however, that seems a bit, well, arbitrary...

In any case, to answer the question you did ask:

> If the mapping is universally constant wouldn't it be the case that this could be pre-computed and available somewhere?

Not really, the effort of pre-computing such a table would be at least $O(2^{128})$ operations; we believe that is infeasible for anyone, even as a one-time effort.  And, generating a rainbow table doesn't decrease this effort any; it just makes the generated table smaller...

Comment: A secure keyed random permutation or a secure keyed pseudorandom permutation?

Comment: @Melab: a keyed operation which is computationally indistinguishable from a random permutation

Answer (score 2):

> Therefore the mapping between H and K should be universally constant.

Well, no, of course not. Because $K$ is not universally constant. It is only constant for the same key. $K$ picks a permutation out of all possible permutations (for the set of keys). And therefore $K$ determines the value of $H$.

> If the mapping is universally constant wouldn't it be the case that this could be pre-computed and available somewhere? (I wanted to say rainbow table here, but that probably doesn't quite apply based on what I read in this response)
>
> So is the strength just that storing this permutation space for later indexing is thought to be too large? Or is there more to it that what I laid out?

Yes, because you cannot pre-compute a rainbow table for things like AES keys. You cannot compute nor store a table of $2^{128}$ elements, or even a large subset of the keys.

Rainbow tables work only for limited input ranges; relatively simple passwords - for instance - are in this category.

Comment: I think the word **mapping** was important here, I never said k was constant. Someone above made a good point that it's not always a bijection, as block size is 128bits and key size is that or greater, hence by pigeonhole it won't be 1:1, but in the case where keysize is 128bits it wouldn't be too far off.

Comment: There is a mapping from K to H. The order is important here because different elements of K will map to the same value within H.